# How to get sum of two column values from SQL table using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]

I have a table name `GRNDtlReturn` in above mention screenshot. I want to get the sum of `ReturnQuantity` of first and third rows in table. I have written some code, but it returns the sum of full `ReturnQuantity` column. Please help me to solve this.

Here's my code:

```
public IList<GRNDtlReturnModel> GetReturnSum()
{
    return igrndtlreturnRepository.GetList (x=> x.GRNNo == "GRN00022"  && x.ProductCode == "D/F/HL/DM/0003/C/002")
            .Select(y => new GRNDtlReturnModel
            {
                GRNNo = y.GRNNo,
                totalQuantity = context.GRNDtlReturns.Sum(p => p.ReturnQuantity)
            }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: why you want to take first and third row? Is there any relation with GRNNo & GRNDtlReturns table?

Comment: First and third rows GRNNo And ProductCode are same,I need to take the sum of ReturnQuantity in same GrNNo and ProductCode.

Comment: Do you even need the returned list or just the first item in the returned list? Second case would allow a different, probably better, answer than the current one.

Comment: @marc_s Aw, the editing trap... thought the question would be a recent one because of the last edit -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public IList<GRNDtlReturnModel> GetReturnSum()
{
        return igrndtlreturnRepository.GetList(x=> x.GRNNo == "GRN00022" && 
                                                x.ProductCode == "D/F/HL/DM/0003/C/002")
            .Select(y => new GRNDtlReturnModel
            {
                GRNNo = y.GRNNo,

                totalQuantity = context.GRNDtlReturns.
                                Where(t=> t.GRNNo==y.GRNNo).Sum(p => p.ReturnQuantity)

            }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `igrndtlreturnRepository.GetList(x => x.GRNNo == grnno && x.ProductCode == productcode)` returns an `IQueryable<GRNDtlReturn>` according to the filter expression.

Case 1: Get a single result for `GRNNo = "GRN00022"` and `ProductCode = "D/F/HL/DM/0003/C/002"`

In this case, the result of `GetList` is already limited to the relevant entries and there should be a single result `GRNDtlReturnModel` if any row matches the criteria.

```
GRNDtlReturnModel result = igrndtlreturnRepository.GetList(x => x.GRNNo == "GRN00022" && x.ProductCode == "D/F/HL/DM/0003/C/002")
    .GroupBy(x => x.GRNNo, (k, v) => new GRNDtlReturnModel { GRNNo = k, totalQuantity = v.Sum(q => q.ReturnQuantity) })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Case 2: Get the group-sum for all matching combinations of `GRNNo` and `ProductCode`

In this case, the grouping expression needs to contain all relevant group keys, the calculation of sum stays the same.

```
IList<GRNDtlReturnModel> result = igrndtlreturnRepository.GetList(x => true)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.GRNNo, x.ProductCode }, (k, v) => new GRNDtlReturnModel { GRNNo = k.GRNNo, totalQuantity = v.Sum(q => q.ReturnQuantity) })
    .ToList();
```

This should be more efficient than a nested access to `context.GRNDtlReturns`.